# What exactly does the rexp()-method in R do?

Tags: r, probability-density

i am trying to generate random values for an Exp(0.5) distribution. 
I have the following code :

```
y <- rexp(10, rate=1/2)    
y
```

This gives me:

```
 [1] 4.5582556 2.3285161 4.2466828 0.9995597 3.6326827 0.1016917 0.2518124
 [8] 0.3189424 0.8553740 0.8277078
```

The problem i have here is that i don´t know what this values mean. They can´t be values of the density function of Exp(1/2) which is [image: density function], because the density function is defined as 0 for x < 0 and f(x) = 4.55 for x < 0.

What do these values mean?

Comment: No i am looking for rexp. I need to get random random variables X_1, ..., X_10 which are Exp(1/2) distributed.

Comment: Oh my god, i feel like an idiot now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming to **R** from statistics, for any distribution:

```
d - PDF
p - CDF
q - inverse CDF
r - sampling according to PDF
```